# TV app doesn't show some episodes

Tags: ios, tv.app

I just ripped a few episodes of a TV show, added them to iTunes, updated the metadata, then synchronized them to my iPhone 6 running iOS 10. However, the episode doesn't show in the TV app. Other episodes that I ripped and synchronized *do* show up.

When I look in Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage > Manage Storage > TV, it shows the missing episodes, so they are on the device.

**Why doesn't the TV app show some of my TV show episodes?**

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the TV app lists episodes from left to right, not up and down. I had to swipe left to see the "missing" episodes. What made this tricky to discover is that the first page of episodes show up below the bottom of my screen, which requires a swipe up to see them. So, you have to know to swipe up *and* left.